# Indenting a function to recursively find filenames

Tags: python, file-system, callback

I wrote this function that recursively traverses a given directory resolves
the relative file-names to absolute file-names and yields the resolved file-name if it matches a given pattern. You can specify a callback function as well.

The first issue I have with this function is that it is a bit hard to comprehend, I think this problem can be reduced with proper indentation of the generator expressions.

The second thing I would like help with is, How do i reduce the repeated block of code?

```
import fnmatch
import os
import sys

def find(root, pattern, *callback):
    if not callback:
        for _, _, files in  ((root, _, (os.path.join(root, filename)
        for filename in files if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, pattern)))
        for (root, _, files) in os.walk(root)):
            for filename in files:
                yield filename

    callback = callback[0]
    for _, _, files in  ((root, _, (os.path.join(root, filename)
    for filename in files if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, pattern)))
    for (root, _, files) in os.walk(root)):
        for filename in files:
            yield callback(filename)



def cb(filename):
    print filename


for filename in find('/home/dwilson', '*.py', cb):
    pass
```

Comment: You seem to be very concerned about performance. Keep in mind, however, that most of the work involves the OS and filesystem I/O. You should therefore avoid mangling your code in search of optimizations that have negligible performance benefit.

Answer (score 2):

A good way would be to eliminate duplicate using a default callback that does nothing:

```
def walker(root, pattern):
    for _, _, files in  ((root, _, (os.path.join(root, filename)
        for filename in files if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, pattern)))
        for (root, _, files) in os.walk(root)):
            for filename in files:
                yield filename

def find(root, pattern, callback=lambda v:v):
    for filename in walker(root, pattern):
        yield callback(filename)
```

Afterwards, we simplify the `walker` to

```
def walker(root, pattern):
    for (root, _, files) in os.walk(root):
        for filename in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, pattern):
                yield os.path.join(root, filename)
```

and have a much more readable thing than before.

Comment: This approach is to slow, generator expressions are far faster then for loops, Also they are more pythonic.

Comment: I just made `timeit` measurements and found that the 2nd approach is indeed slightly faster - but only a few %. And readable code is definitely more pythonic than unreadable one...

Comment: If space is not a constraint and speed is paramount, list comprehensions are usually faster than generators because generators generate a bit of overhead.

Comment: @myself For large amount of data generators can be not only more efficient but also faster.

Comment: pylint tells me my code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00) so according to pep8 my code is pythonic

Comment: @RickyWilson, I strongly doubt that pylint may recognize cluttered code with over-complicated logic..... I can see one redundancy right now - asterick operator before *callback*. I would say that more Pythonic approach would be default *None* value - though I prefer my default *lambda* twist

Answer (score 1):

I think I need my own space to explain "my approach" with default *lambda* - thanks to [glglgl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296974/glglgl) for hospitality :) .

It saves you from having to check condition in the function. And the overhead? Not that much (here comes *dis*, which I - alas! - nearly never use)

```
dis.dis(lambda v: v)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (v)
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

But how bad is it - compared to other approaches? See below

```
>>> def test1(param, callback=lambda v:v):
    return callback(param)

>>> def test2(param, *callback):
    if callback:
        return callback[0](param)
    else:
        return param

>>> def test3(param, callback=None):
    if callback is not None:
        return callback(param)
    else:
        return param

>>> dis.dis(test1)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (callback)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (param)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(test2)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (callback)
              3 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       20

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                1 (callback)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             12 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             13 LOAD_FAST                0 (param)
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             19 RETURN_VALUE        

  5     >>   20 LOAD_FAST                0 (param)
             23 RETURN_VALUE        
             24 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             27 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(test3)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (callback)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 COMPARE_OP               9 (is not)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       22

  3          12 LOAD_FAST                1 (callback)
             15 LOAD_FAST                0 (param)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             21 RETURN_VALUE        

  5     >>   22 LOAD_FAST                0 (param)
             25 RETURN_VALUE        
             26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             29 RETURN_VALUE
```

Surprise, surprise, *None* loses by 2 bytecodes (did not see it coming), still - it is cleaner that **callback*, which in semantically misleading, since it implies possibility of more than one value. And default callback overhead is less than 25% of any

As for run-time impact - try timing runs with different implementations, and see for yourself

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I got rid of the duplicated block of code but the list comprehensions are still hard to follow, And i wrote them...

I don't like how for each iteration of the loop the function has to check to see if a callback was given.

```
import fnmatch
import os
import sys

def find(root, pattern, *callback):

    for _, _, files in  ((root, _, (os.path.join(root, filename)
    for filename in files if fnmatch.fnmatch(filename, pattern)))
    for (root, _, files) in os.walk(root)):
        for filename in files:
            if not callback:
                yield filename
            else:
                yield callback[0](filename)

def print_filename(filename):
    print filename


for filename in find('/', '*.c', print_filename):
    pass
```

Comment: My approach would be checking once, like *callback = callback[0] if callback else lambda v: v*. Even (IMHO) better approach - do it in function signature *def find(root, pattern, callback=lambda v:v):*

Comment: @volcano Your approach would cause a lambda function to be called for every iteration for no reason, Or maybe I'm confused. 
The reason I chose to use optional args aka *args is that i wanted the callback function to be optional. Could you elaborate more on your approach?
PS. Thanks from the input.

Answer (score 0):

I took the liberty of using shortened names due to the constraints of
interactivity but I hope that you can decide if this suggestion is good
enough for your use case.

Here follows a (slightly edited) `ipython` interactive session.

```
In [38]: from os.path import join as j
In [39]: from os import walk as w
In [40]: from fnmatch import fnmatch as fm
In [41]: def x(r,p,*c):
    g = (j(r,fn) for r, dl, fl in w(r) for fn in fl if fm(fn,p))
    return (c[0](fn) for fn in g) if c else g
   ....: 
In [42]: x('bin','*py*')
Out[42]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fdf7411cc30>
In [43]: list(x('bin','*py*'))
Out[43]: 
['bin/pythontex_engines.py',
 ...,
 'bin/pythontex2.py']
In [44]: x('bin','*py*',lambda s:s.split('/'))
Out[44]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fdf7411cd20>
In [45]: list(x('bin','*py*',lambda s:s.split('/')))
Out[45]: 
[['bin', 'pythontex_engines.py'],
 ...,
 ['bin', 'pythontex2.py']]
In [46]:
```

As you have noticed, my code doesn't `yield` a file name but rather it
returns a generator object... that's not exactly what you want but its
use in a `for` loop is the same and other use cases can be easily
taken into account.

#### Another take at it

As the question was about proper indentation, I'm ambigously, ashamedly proud of this new attempt of mine...

```
def find(root, pattern, *callback):

    from os.path import join
    from os import walk
    from fnmatch import fnmatch

    gen = (join(cr, fn)

#   Trompe-l'oeil code

    for cr, dl, fl in walk(root)
        for fn in fl
            if fnmatch(fn, pattern))
#               join(cr, fn) )

    return (callback[0](fn) for fn in gen) if callback else gen
```